# What is different in the Android JVM?

Tags: java, android, jvm

As in the question title, how the Android JVM differ from other JVMs ??

Comment: The Android 'JVM' isn't strictly a JVM in the sense of the 'normal' desktop/server VMs. Android uses the Java programming language to compile down to its own byte code, not 'normal' JVM byte code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is not a JVM
- It executes Dalvik bytecode, not Java bytecode
- It differs from the JVM by being a register-based, as opposed to stack-based VM

Comment: Can you not search for it, perhaps using Google.com?  They are not new concepts.

Answer (score 3):

To add to my comments, [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).